# Unable to understand this JS code [Array and Filter]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I came across a question which asked us to

> combine  arrays
>
> ```
> var array1 = [1, 2, 3]; 
> var array2 = [2, 30, 1];
> ```

and then remove all duplicate items so expected output was

```
[1, 2, 3, 30]
```

in the comment section there was this solution which I'm unable to understand:

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [2, 30, 1];
function concatArrays(array1, array2){
    var concated = array1.concat(array2);
    var solution = concated.filter(function(element,Index,self){
        return Index== self.indexOf(element);
    });
console.log(solution);
}
concatArrays(array1,array2);
```

So I want to understand this line

```
var solution = concated.filter(function(element,Index,self){
        return Index == self.indexOf(element);
    });
```

I know what the filter method does, but then in the return part I'm unable to understand his code.
This is what I think the return part does:
Compare `index of element` with the `index of current element`. If it's equal then return else don't do anything.
I don't know if my interpretation is right or wrong.

Comment: What part about the return don't you understand? Its comparing 2 indices.

Comment: <b>EDITED </b>
@Carcigenicate its comparing two indices then how is it able to remove Duplicate value ??
example 
if element is 1 and then its converted into 0 using indexOf() after that its compared to index of its own element so how is it able to remove duplicate data ?

Comment: It compares the *current index* with the index of the *first occurance* of this element in the array. And the uppercase `Index` in this code stinks; it's no class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert an output for every step of the filter loop and check the values, you get

> ```
>                                                    result
>   element       index     indexOf   comparison      array
> ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
>         1           0           0        true           1
>         2           1           1        true           2
>         3           2           2        true           3
>         2           3           1       false
>        30           4           4        true          30
>         1           5           0       false
> ```

As you see, the item gets in the result if the comparison is `true`. That means, the actual element's index has to the same as the value of [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). `indexOf` returns the first index of the wanted item or `-1` if not found. Therefore if the index and the value of `indexOf` is not equal, then you have the second or third value found, but not the first.

```js
function concatArrays(array1, array2) {
    var concated = array1.concat(array2);
    console.log('element', 'Index', 'indexOf', 'comparison');
    var solution = concated.filter(function (element, Index, self) {
        console.log(element, Index, self.indexOf(element), Index == self.indexOf(element));
            return Index == self.indexOf(element);
        });
    console.log(solution);
}

var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [2, 30, 1];

concatArrays(array1, array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Filetr function is realy easy it creates new array based on prev array and passed function.
If function passed returns true element is pushed else not.

This is simple implemenation of this function to help you understand it:

```js
function Filter(array, func) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (func(array[i], i, array)) {
      newArray.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(Filter([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], function(element, index, self){
    return index == self.indexOf(element);
}))
```

Now if we iterate over array elements and for each we check if that item is found at it index because `indexOf` returns first index found we don't add duplicates.

Comment: You had a typo in `found`